# Is there any way to send data from AWS Kinesis to Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-eventhub, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

My company is doing a POC on some streaming data and one of the tasks is sending data from AWS Kinesis to Azure Event Hubs.

Has anyone tryed to do something like this before?

I was thinking of a lambda function listening to kinesis firehose and sending the data to event hubs but I have no experience on Azure at all and I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very much possible.

Inter-Cloud environment where data can be streamed among two services can be achieved using AWS Kinesis and Azure Event Hub.

You can stream data from Amazon Kinesis directly to Azure Event Hub in Real-Time. Using ‘serverless’ model and cloud computing to process and transfer events without having the need to manage any native application written on an on-premise server.

You will be required connection string, `SharedAccessKeyName`, and `SharedAccessKey` from the Azure Event Hub. This will be needed to send data to Event Hub. Also, make sure the Event hub can receive data from the IP address you are running the program from.

Refer this [third-party tutorial](https://prathameshmahadik2013.medium.com/serverless-streaming-data-in-inter-cloud-aws-azure-environment-forming-a-hybrid-cloud-e5f73d86569e) to accomplish the same