# Consume Azure Event Hub events to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-eventhub, amazon-kinesis, aws-event-bridge

We have a requirement as below

- A publisher is using MS Azure and will be publishing events to the EventHub in Azure
- We expect around 4000 events per second now and over time this will go to around 60000 events      per second over time
- We want to ingest these events into AWS cloud

I want to check whether there are any out of the box integration between EventHub to say Kinesis or EventBridge?

Please note we are looking for a plug and play solution or service.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71494593/2570277) answer help ?

Comment: No this one talks of going from Kinesis to Event hub. We want to bring events from event hub to kinesis